# Laravel: Authenticate an Authenticatable Model statelessly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I need help.

Current situation, I have a Company model. That company model refers to a Client Credentials grant OAuth Client (passport).
I managed to make a middleware that resolves the current Company from request via the passed bearer token of the API request.

The problem:  I want to set that Company instance as the currently authenticated user statelessly.
In the docs, there is a `once()` method from the `Auth` facade. (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#other-authentication-methods)
However, the `once()` only accepts credentials, not an `Authenticatable` instance.

Is there a similar method to `Auth::once()` that accepts an Authenticatable instance instead of credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, in a stateless endpoint (e.g. passport protected routes), `Auth::login()` doesn't store any cookie/session because it can't.

So just use `Auth::login()` directly.